# Is there a way I can use a struct to generate Swagger JSON/TOML, so I can upload it to Yapi and share it with others?

Tags: go, swagger

I need to share some JSON proto using the TCP protocol with others.

Yapi supports only HTTP APIs, which require specifying paths and methods. Additionally, Swagger comments must be written before a function, but in my case, I only have a struct and don't need a function.